# Find the length of the curve $y = \frac{x^4}{16} + \frac{1}{2x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$y = \frac{x^4}{16} + \frac{1}{2x^2}$, $1 \leq x \leq 2$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{4} - \frac{1}{x^3}dx$
$$\begin{align}
L &= \int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1 + \bigg[ \frac{x^3}{4} - \frac{1}{x^3} \bigg]^2}dx \\
&= \int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{1 + \bigg[ \frac{x^6-4}{4x^3}\bigg]^2}dx \\
&= \int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\frac{(4x^3)^2 + (x^6-4)^2}{(4x^3)^2}}dx
\end{align}$$

I tried splitting the $\sqrt{~~}$ into the numerator and denominator, but that didn't really get me anywhere and I am stuck. Can someone give me a hint in the right direction possibly?

edit: continuing on...

$$\begin{align} 
L &= \int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{\frac{(x^6+4)^2}{(4x^3)^2}}dx \\
&= \int_{1}^{2} \frac{(x^6+4)}{(4x^3)} \\
&= 4 \int_{1}^{2} \frac{x^6+4}{x^3}dx \\
&= 4\int_{1}^{2} \bigg(x^3 + \frac{4}{x^3}\bigg)dx \\
&= 4 \bigg[ \frac{1}{4}x^4 - \frac{2}{x^2} \bigg]_{1}^{2} \\
&= 4 \bigg[ (4-\frac{1}{2}) - (\frac{1}{4} - 2)\bigg] \\
&= 21
\end{align}$$

However wolphram alpha says the answer is actually $\frac{21}{16}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(4x^3)^2 + (x^6-4)^2$$
$$=16x^6 + x^{12} + 16 - 8x^6$$
$$=(x^6+4)^2$$

So that square root will open up straight away.

Comment: ah, I factored $(x^6+4)^2$ wrong, did it too hastily. I see my error, thank you!

Comment: Yeah sure. No problem!

Comment: Hey...I updated my work. I got to the end, but I think I integrated improperly after opening the square root up :/

Comment: Yeah why did you send that $4$ in the numerator?

Comment: $= \int_{1}^{2} \frac{(x^6+4)}{(4x^3)}$... your error is after this line when you mistakenly take $4$ in the numerator

Comment: I guess I was being sloppy:( Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure. Please mark the answer as accepted. :)